# javascript equality operation succeeds for both single quote string and number

Tags: javascript

- I try to check error code coming back from mongo in node.js server
- Comparison succeeds in both the cases
- Which one is the correct one and should be used?
- Please excuse my limited understanding on this.

I have code like this

```
        if (err['code'] == '11000') {
          console.log("Single Quote String");
        }
        if (err['code'] == 11000) {
          console.log("With out single quote");
        }
```

Output is:

```
Single Quote String
With out single quote
```

Comment: Try '===' (triple equals)

Comment: Thank you all VERY VERY much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should almost always use the 'strict equality' check in javascript, which is three equals: `===` rather than `==`

when you use `==`, javascript will take liberties in doing type casting for you for the purpose of the operation.  strings and ints are comparable this way, falesy values, etc. you generally should just never use `==` for any reason.

more examples:

`null == undefined; // true`

`null === undefined; // false`

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to be certain, you should coerce the values to the same type. like this:

```
if ( String(err['code']) == '11000') {
      console.log("Single Quote String");
    }
    if ( parseFloat( err['code'] ) == 11000) {
      console.log("With out single quote");
    }
```

If you do not need to do any mathematical calculations with the error code, then string is the simplest way to go, since the parseFlat() function in some browsers can fail if the string has certain characters in it.

[Here is a link to parseFloat() explained.](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&sqi=2&ved=0CC8QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fjsref_parsefloat.asp&ei=zHcIVZfTGYu4oQSq0YHYAw&usg=AFQjCNGXn142rH0uy3GgMyih2s_LCamXbQ&bvm=bv.88528373,d.cGU)

You can also use strict equality with "===". Either works!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is not strongly-typed.  So, it's being a little forgiving.  If you know the error code is always an integer, go without the single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the === operator. The == checks for value equivalence, but does not look at type. You want to look at the type as well.

Whichever value still returns true after you switch both lines to === will be the correct response.